# Add a new Azure website on runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage

I want to add a new website on Azure while runtime.
What i want to do is user enters a subdomain, which then adds it with the main domain and then this creates a new website in Azure.
The required authentication is provided by default.
Suppose I enter 'xyz' , then the result is xyz.mydomain.com

```
public async Task MapDomain(string space, string site, string domain)
    {
        var website = _webManagementClient.WebSites.Get(space, site, new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.Models.WebSiteGetParameters());
        website.WebSite.HostNames.Add("http://" + site + domain);
        await _webManagementClient.WebSites.UpdateAsync(space, site,new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.Models.WebSiteUpdateParameters { HostNames = new List<string> { domain } });
    }
```

What do more i have to add in it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling what you are trying to accomplish is more of a multi-tenancy thing that you might want to design within your app instead of relying on azures per server web site limits and management API.

Check out the below link;
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dotnet-develop-multitenant-applications/

If you build your application in a way it can detect tenants by their host headers the rest of the story is more of a DNS redirection. With a simple wildcard redirection in your DNS and host header tenant detection in your application you can very easily achieve what you are looking for and that would be much more salable than relying on azure web sites management. Obviously you will need to take care of more. Data isolation, security would be just some of them but personally I would go with this. My 2 cents.

Comment: Its like, there is a library, by which if a user enters the name, it becomes the subdomain. Example- if users enters 'test' , the domain 'test.mywebsite.com' registers in Azure. A code would be helpful. See my updated code, does it work?